# Diferença de propriedades de classe vs Instância

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Qual a finalidade de se criar atributos na classe se posso criar na própria instância?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ideia é ter sempre o mesmo conjunto de propriedades a cada classe que é criada, no caso das propriedades de classe.

Você é livre para colocar as propriedades que quiser nas suas classes, mas isso tornará o objeto diferente dos demais da mesma classe.

Em Python, ter este tipo de atribuição não é um problema porque essa característica faz parte da filosofia da linguagem. Seja qual for a nova propriedade que você está colocando no objeto, a nova propriedade não interfere no funcionamento do objeto como ele é definido pela classe.

Answer (score 5):

Um ponto que vale ressaltar é o fato de que um atributo na classe é compartilhado para todas as instâncias, já o atributo em uma instância é exclusivo para a instância.